# show there exist a sequence of natural number $n_k$ such that$\lim_{k \to \infty}\sin{a^{n_k}}$ exist, for a in R

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

> Original Question :  Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$, Show there is a sequenece $n_1 < n_2 < n_3 ...$ of natural numbers such that$\lim_{k \to \infty}\sin{a^{n_k}}$  exist. (The sequence will depend on $a$)

for $-1 < a <= 1$ the sequence obvious converges to 0 for any such sequence of natural numbers.

But for $|a| > 1$ I'm not sure how to approach this at all, perhaps try to approximate multiples of pi?

Any idea or help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you heard of Bolzano-Weierstrass: That a bounded sequence of Reals has a convergent subsequence

Comment: Choose $n_k=\frac12+\frac14+\cdots+\frac1{2^k}$, then the limit is $\sin a$.

Comment: @Szeto the $n_k$ have to be natural numbers

Comment: The limit depends on $x$, which does not appear in the argument of the limit. I think that there must almost certainly be a typo here.

Comment: @John Hughes my bad, should be as k to infinity, fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You consider $b_n = a^n - 2\pi\left[\frac{a^n}{2\pi} \right]$.

Then $0 \leq b_n < 2\pi$ and $\sin b_n = \sin a_n$

According to [Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Bolzano-WeierstrassTheorem.html) there exist a subsequence $b_{n_k}$ which converges. Note, that $\sin$ is continuous.

Hence, $\lim_{k\to\infty }\sin b_{n_k} = \sin \left(\lim_{k\to\infty } b_{n_k}\right)$ Now, take the corresponding $a_{n_k}$.

Comment: why bother with $b_n$? We have $-1\le\sin(a^n)\le1$ so there exists a subsequence $\sin(a^{n_k})$ that converges.

Comment: @Mirko : I didn't feel bothered with $b_n$. :-) . But basically you are right. Still early here.